Module Federation : Getting "Unexpected token export" when routing to Module Using Module Federation in Angular 15
I am using angular 15, implementing module federation. I am using the package @angular-architects/module-federation. I have added module federation using the command
ng add @angular-architects/module-federation.
Now in the shell App when i am navigating to the module, I can see the remoteEntry.js file in the network tab. but the module is not loading, i am getting error
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token 'export' (at remoteEntry.js:7762:10) 
Line at which i am getting error
ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'init')
TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'init')
    at angular-architects-module-federation-runtime.mjs:22:21
    at Generator.next (<anonymous>)
    at asyncGeneratorStep (asyncToGenerator.js:3:1)
    at _next (asyncToGenerator.js:22:1)
    at _ZoneDelegate.invoke (zone.js:375:26)
    at Object.onInvoke (core.mjs:24210:33)
    at _ZoneDelegate.invoke (zone.js:374:52)
    at Zone.run (zone.js:134:43)
    at zone.js:1278:36
    at _ZoneDelegate.invokeTask (zone.js:409:31)
    at angular-architects-module-federation-runtime.mjs:22:21
    at Generator.next (<anonymous>)
    at asyncGeneratorStep (asyncToGenerator.js:3:1)
    at _next (asyncToGenerator.js:22:1)
    at _ZoneDelegate.invoke (zone.js:375:26)
    at Object.onInvoke (core.mjs:24210:33)
    at _ZoneDelegate.invoke (zone.js:374:52)
    at Zone.run (zone.js:134:43)
    at zone.js:1278:36
    at _ZoneDelegate.invokeTask (zone.js:409:31)
    at resolvePromise (zone.js:1214:31)
    at zone.js:1121:17
    at zone.js:1137:33
    at asyncGeneratorStep (asyncToGenerator.js:6:1)
    at _next (asyncToGenerator.js:22:1)
    at _ZoneDelegate.invoke (zone.js:375:26)
    at Object.onInvoke (core.mjs:24210:33)
    at _ZoneDelegate.invoke (zone.js:374:52)
    at Zone.run (zone.js:134:43)
    at zone.js:1278:36

Attaching below the webpack.config.js of both the applications.
mfe app
const ModuleFederationPlugin = require("webpack/lib/container/ModuleFederationPlugin");
const mf = require("@angular-architects/module-federation/webpack");
const path = require("path");
const share = mf.share;

const sharedMappings = new mf.SharedMappings();
sharedMappings.register(path.join(__dirname, "tsconfig.json"), [
  /* mapped paths to share */
]);

module.exports = {
  output: {
    uniqueName: "v17",
    publicPath: "auto",
    scriptType: "text/javascript",
  },
  optimization: {
    runtimeChunk: false,
  },
  resolve: {
    alias: {
      ...sharedMappings.getAliases(),
    },
  },
  experiments: {
    outputModule: true,
  },
  plugins: [
    new ModuleFederationPlugin({
      library: { type: "module" },

      // For remotes (please adjust)
      name: "v17",
      filename: "remoteEntry.js",
      exposes: {
        "./SupersetModule": "src/app/superset/superset.module.ts",
      },

      // For hosts (please adjust)
      // remotes: {
      //   mfe1: "http://localhost:4300/remoteEntry.js",
      // },

      shared: share({
        "@angular/core": { singleton: true, strictVersion: true, requiredVersion: 'auto' },
        "@angular/common": { singleton: true, strictVersion: true, requiredVersion: 'auto' },
        "@angular/common/http": { singleton: true, strictVersion: true, requiredVersion: 'auto' },
        "@angular/router": { singleton: true, strictVersion: true, requiredVersion: 'auto' },
        ...sharedMappings.getDescriptors()
      }),
    }),
    sharedMappings.getPlugin(),
  ],
};


--- Host App
const ModuleFederationPlugin = require("webpack/lib/container/ModuleFederationPlugin");
const mf = require("@angular-architects/module-federation/webpack");
const path = require("path");
const share = mf.share;

const sharedMappings = new mf.SharedMappings();
sharedMappings.register(path.join(__dirname, "tsconfig.json"), [
  /* mapped paths to share */
]);

module.exports = {
  output: {
    uniqueName: "shell",
    publicPath: "auto",
    scriptType: "text/javascript",
  },
  optimization: {
    runtimeChunk: false,
  },
  resolve: {
    alias: {
      ...sharedMappings.getAliases(),
    },
  },
  experiments: {
    outputModule: true,
  },
  plugins: [
    new ModuleFederationPlugin({
      library: { type: "module" },

      // For remotes (please adjust)
      name: "shell",
      // filename: "remoteEntry.js",
      // exposes: {
      //     './Component': './/src/app/app.component.ts',
      // },

      // For hosts (please adjust)
      remotes: {
        v17: "v17@http://localhost:3000/remoteEntry.js",
      },

      shared: share({
        "@angular/core": {
          singleton: true,
          strictVersion: true,
          requiredVersion: "auto",
        },
        "@angular/common": {
          singleton: true,
          strictVersion: true,
          requiredVersion: "auto",
        },
        "@angular/common/http": {
          singleton: true,
          strictVersion: true,
          requiredVersion: "auto",
        },
        "@angular/router": {
          singleton: true,
          strictVersion: true,
          requiredVersion: "auto",
        },

        ...sharedMappings.getDescriptors(),
      }),
    }),
    sharedMappings.getPlugin(),
  ],
};



I have gone through multiple blogs and no one has mentioned these errors. tried setting up multiple set ups for the same but resulting the same error.
